# How to Implement Relational Operation using TCAM?

Tags: asic

Can we implement relational operations (<, > , >=, <= ) using [TCAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs)? Even if they are possible to implement, are TCAMs used for relational operations in real life? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

No, it is not normally done. Ordinary gates (LUTs on an FPGA) are far more efficient.

To compare two N-bit operands, it would require a N × 2N TCAM, but only N 4-input LUTs in an FPGA, or the equivalent amount of logic in an ASIC.